# Can the MySQL general query log be turned on for a single database only?

Tags: mysql, database, logging

I'd like to turn on MySQL's general query log for a single database only. By default, it records all statements sent to all databases, resulting in huge log files on servers with many databases.

Is it possible to only record statements sent to a particular database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general query log is a global log of all queries executed on a given server, so it is not possible to enable or disable it for a specific schema.

There is a variable called [`SQL_LOG_OFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_off) that disables general query logging for a specific connection, which maybe useful for you if you can isolate specific connections that use the schema for which you want to enable/disable the general query log:

```
SET SQL_LOG_OFF = 1;
```

Note that this only works for users with SUPER privilege, so it may not be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, useful to know there's a way to disable logging although needing the SUPER privilege is problematic.

Comment: If you could site a definitive source for it not being possible to turn the log off, I'd be happy to accept your answer for this question.

Comment: Here's the doc page for the general query log, notice no mention of a feature to enable/disable for specific schemas: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 6):

General query is enabled by LOG option, it is a global variable, so you cannot set it for one database. But log size can be decreased; disable logging for the server in the ini-file and if it is possible - enable it using SET command in your scripts (only when you need it).

```
SET GLOBAL LOG := 1;  -- enable log
-- execute queries
SET GLOBAL LOG := 0;  -- disable log
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but if the log's turned on it will also record any queries run on other databases on the same server.

To isolate one databases' queries this could be done in a transaction that first locks all other databases, then enables the log, runs the query, disables the log and then unlocks all. But the impact on the server of having all of those databases unavailable would be problematic.

Comment: What to do if INSERT..SELECT statement grabs data from one database and inserts into another? I want to say that loging should be enabled just for debugging purposes.

Comment: It's a gap, but this question is specifically about logging single databases on a server. Sometimes that's all that's needed.